# Create view from not empty table postgresql

Tags: postgresql, view, postgresql-11

everyone!

I have 2 tables: t1 and t2. They are almost the same (by column), but in different schemes s1 and s2.

So I need to create view from t1 if it not empty or from t2 (if t1 empty).

Example:

```
s1.t1.  s2.t2
1        2
2       10
3        2

view:
1
2
3
```

Second:

```
s1.t1.    s2.t2
<empty>.    1
            2
            9

View:
1
2
9
```

Comment: Please post what have you tried and where are you having problems. Your query code would be very helpful for example.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query could be

```
SELECT * FROM t1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM t2
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t1);
```